# Removing whitespace from CSS grid issue

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've made a grid in CSS but have a problem with whitespace. There seems to be too much whitespace in between the grid and I can't seem to find the error causing it. I'm new to web development so I might be missing something very obvious or perhaps have over-coded the feature.

I've put a diagram of how I would like it to look and the current way it looks below as well as the code. Thanks for taking the time :)

Currently looks like:
[image]

How I'd like it to look:
[image]

Here's the code:

```css
  .site {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.site-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 6rem 0;
  /* Homepage code */
  .homepage {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    min-height: 280px;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .topics {
    justify-self: stretch;
    min-width: 500px;
  }
  .homepage-recent-title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    align-self: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 50%
  }
  .homepage-topics-title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    align-self: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .individual-topics {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 5rem;
    padding-right: 50%;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    align-items: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 3;
  }
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
  <div class="topics">
    <div class="homepage-topics-title">
      Explore some topics:
    </div>
    <div class="individual-topics">
      <a href="/productivity" class="topic1">Productivity</a>
      <a href="/orginisation" class="topic2">Orginisation</a>
      <a href="/time-management" class="topic3">Time-Management</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recent">
    <div class="homepage-recent-title">
      Recent articles
    </div>
    <div class="hompage-recent-articles">
      {{{body}}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet. Please note that you're missing some HTML elements for which you have defined important CSS behaviors. (See [mcve].) You can edit the snippet and add them.

Comment: You have an unclosed css declation just before `/* Homepage code */`

Comment: Otherwise it seems to work fine - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LYyyaMG

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting `gap` property in your `.site` class. And `justify-content: stretch` for `.topics` class. When using the value stretch flex distributes items evenly to stretch 'auto'-sized items to fit the container, in your case  div with `.topics` class.

```css
  .site {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  gap: 0px;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content